# Invalid variable sass error

Tags: sass

I'm trying to convert a sass file to scss using sass-convert, but when I run the command or even when I run compass watch I get the following error:

```
Invalid variable: $media (min-width: 950px)
```

I usually work with the scss syntax so I'm not sure why this is generating an error, should it be @media?

The section of the code is:

```
.center  text-align:center 
.right  text-align:right 
.top vertical-align:top 
.middle  vertical-align:middle 
$media (min-width: 950px) 
.row
    max-width:980px


$media (max-width: 900px) 
.row
    max-width:760px

.logo
    width:300px
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Did you *try* changing it to `@media`?

Comment: I did and that only generated more errors. So I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a number of formatting erros in your code!

- Declarations can't be inline with selector.
- There should be at least one space in every declaration immediately after the colon, otherwise it's treated as pseudoclass.
- A media block starts with a `@`, not `$`. `$` is for variables.
- Rules inside media blocks should be properly nested.

Here's your code properly formatted:

```
.center
  text-align: center 

.right
  text-align: right 

.top
  vertical-align: top 

.middle
  vertical-align: middle 

@media (min-width: 950px) 
  .row
    max-width: 980px


@media (max-width: 900px) 
  .row
    max-width: 760px

  .logo
    width: 300px
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm modifying someone else's code and I'm not familiar with the SASS syntax, only SCSS, so your explanation of the issues was very helpful and much appreciated!